# Why can the hypervisor not see RAM utilization?

Tags: cpu

On AWS, I noticed that their CloudWatch tool cannot see memory utilization of EC2 instances. I can, on the other hand, see CPU utilization, network metrics, etc.

Why is it that a hypervisor can see the CPU but not the RAM utilization of instances?

Answer (score 3):

When ram is allocated to a VM(Guest), the VM is using it.  The host does not know if the values stored in the ram is relevant or not.

The OS running in a VM keeps track of Ram assigned, but it does not have to ask the Host for ram.

It is easy for the host to keep track of stats for things entering or leaving the VM e.g. Network packets or Disk read's and writes.

The problem with ram is that for the time slice the VM has the CPU it can read/modify/write to it's allocated ram without any visibility by the host.

This is also the reason that changing the RAM dynamically is not really a option.  One way around this is with a baloon driver loaded in the Guest, it can then chat with a back channel to the Host, asking for ram from the Guest where it runs, and then informing the Host it is locked and can be removed.

When the user then decides to add more ram, the balloon driver informs the guest it does not need the ram it was holding.